# Use window aggregation functions with joining SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, join, window-functions, netezza

please the below SQL code, I need to Join **TTS** table with **CMS** table where `CMS.NEW_COLLECTED_DIGITS = TTS.FULLNUM` and I need to join also `TTS.LAST_UDATE_DATE with CMS.Call_Date` but the challenge is I need to get `TTS.LAST_UDATE_DATE between CMS.Call_Date AND CMS.Call_Date + '01:00:00'::"INTERVAL"` and LAST_UDATE_DATE has many records in the CMS.Call_Date period interval and I need to get only the Max one,

And the below query gives me this error: **expression_tree_walker: Unexpected node type 801**

like the below sample

```
|FullNum    |LAST_UDATE_DATE    |Call_Date        |
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:10:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:13:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:14:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:20:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:30:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:40:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:50:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
```

the result will be:

```
|FullNum    |LAST_UDATE_DATE    |Call_Date        |
|123456     |6/4/2020 18:50:11  |6/4/2020 18:00:11|
```

the code is

```
-- Step 1: 
-- Get Call Date From IVR with CMS.CALL_HEADER
 WITH CMS AS (
SELECT CALL_DATE, New_COLLECTED_DIGITS
FROM CMS),

-- Step 2
--Gett All TTS Logs Table
 TTS AS (
SELECT ITEM_ID, FullNum,  LAST_UDATE_DATE
FROM TTS)
-- Join CMS with TTS while ADSL_Phone_Num is matched and ticket log date is between call date and call date plus one hour
 SELECT *
FROM CMS
LEFT JOIN TTS ON
    CMS.NEW_COLLECTED_DIGITS = TTS.FULLNUM
    AND (FIRST_Value (TTS.LAST_UDATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY TTS.ITEM_ID ORDER BY TTS.LAST_UDATE_DATE DESC )
    BETWEEN CMS.Call_Date AND CMS.Call_Date + '01:00:00'::"INTERVAL")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . from the way you describe your question, you can use a `join` and then `row_number()` to choose the most recent record for each cms call record:

```
select ct.*
from (select . . . , -- list the columns you want here,
             row_number() over (partition by cms.new_collect_digits, cms.call_date order by tts.last_update_date desc) as seqnum
      from cms left join
           tts
           on cms.new_collect_digits = tts.fullnum and
              tts.last_update_date between cms.call_date and cms.call_date + '01:00:00'::"INTERVAL"
     ) ct
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It gives me this error:  found "ROW_NUMBER" (at char 1784) expecting `')'' where could I add these parentheses

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader . . . The row number is syntactically correct.  Did you replace the `. . . ` with the columns you want, as the comment says to do.

Comment: Yes I did it, I've added the list of other columns